# What is it called when someone deliberately feigns misunderstanding in order to make a joke?

Tags: single-word-requests, literary-device

I used to think this is irony, but after searching for the definition of "irony", it clearly isn't. It also isn't sarcasm. Here's an example:

> Person 1: Hey, do you know Newton's second law?
>
> Person 2: No, I'm a science student, not a law student.

Person 2 is making a joke by pretending that they do not know what Newton's second law is. Is there a name for this? Person 2 is being _____ ?

Comment: Not sure if [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64614/idiom-phrase-which-means-to-pretend-not-to-understand-or-know) is the same: it's more about pretending to be stupid to get out of doing a favor. [This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44330/a-word-for-a-worldly-wise-person-who-pretends-to-be-na%c3%afve) is different again, but some answers may still apply.

Comment: All that's happening here is *playing dumb*.

Answer (score 1):

Such a person is answering in a *[deadpan](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=deadpan)* manner:

> **deadpan**, *adj*.: deliberately impassive or expressionless

Answer (score 1):

**Deliberately obtuse**, maybe? Deadpan is probably better, but I just want to put it out there.

> **[deliberately](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deliberately)**, *adv.*: with full awareness of what one is doing : in a way that is intended or planned

> **[obtuse](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/obtuse)**, *adj*.: stupid and slow to understand, or unwilling to try to understand:

If you put the two together, you get something along the lines of:
*Intentionally unwilling or slow to understand [for the purpose of being humorous or uncooperative]*

(The example in the definition for obtuse (link 2) actually uses the construction 'deliberately obtuse.')

But I would still use deadpan because it's a) more common, and b) the humorous intent is inherent rather than implied.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pun. It's more subtle than the usual sort, but it's a joke made by conflating two different meanings of the word "law" (a rule made by people, or a natural phenomenon). It feels less pun-like since in a normal pun, the meanings are completely different, whereas here they're similar.

A traditional pun is a groaner like "give peas a chance". But they can require more understanding, such as "politics and golf both depend on having a good lie". Or look at the things from [80 funniest puns](https://www.boredpanda.com/funny-pun-jokes/) that play a bit loose, like "Last night, I dreamed I was swimming in an ocean of orange soda. But it was just a Fanta sea".