# English equivalent of this Tamil saying

Tags: phrases, proverbs, proverb-requests

There is a famous saying in Tamil language: *"Paarthaal pasu pol, paaindhaal puli pol"* which translates to *"Looks like a cow, leaps like a tiger"*.

This is usually used to describe a person who on first look gives an impression that they are silent and submissive, but when confronted, they dominate the confronter.

The closest English proverb which I could think of is *Appearances are deceptive*, but it doesn't essentially capture the silent nature and the combative nature of a person.

Is there an English saying which means the same?

Comment: Related: [Expression for a “smiling face tiger”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188010/expression-for-a-smiling-face-tiger), [What's an expression for a cunningly-fake friend?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258101/whats-an-expression-for-a-cunningly-fake-friend) and [Someone who is cunning but depicts themselves as innocent to others](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248841/someone-who-is-cunning-but-depicts-themselves-as-innocent-to-others?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: also related: [A word for a worldly wise person who pretends to be naïve?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44330/a-word-for-a-worldly-wise-person-who-pretends-to-be-na%C3%AFve?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [A word for someone trying to make people underestimate him](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42203/a-word-for-someone-trying-to-make-people-underestimate-him) and [What is an idiom/slang for “someone who pretends to be good when they're not”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42404/what-is-an-idiom-slang-for-someone-who-pretends-to-be-good-when-theyre-not)

Comment: and...[A good noun for a two-faced person](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24216/a-good-noun-for-a-two-faced-person)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is of course the expression of the [wolf in sheep's clothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_in_sheep%27s_clothing), which is of biblical origin:

> A Wolf in sheep's clothing is an idiom of Biblical origin used to describe those playing a role contrary to their real character with whom contact is dangerous, particularly false teachers.